# Detect specific part of url change

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hashchange

I am having problem of detecting change on my url , problem is that , that i use same first part of url after # ,example

```
mySite.com/masterPage.html#pageView=employee&employeeCode=10
```

If i listen for changes with window.onhashchange = function(); ,it doesnt detect changes if i just change url to

```
 mySite.com/masterPage.html#pageView=student
```

Because hash has stayed same as before , any ideas how to detect change of pageView on url change

Comment: If you are triggering the change can you not track it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with jQuery, works fine for me.

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function(){
    alert('change');
});
```

Tested whith mySite.fr/#toto and mySite.fr/#tototata 
Event was fired when anchor changed.

Comment: Read question , that will not detect if first part after # stays the same

Comment: read response, i tested my solution with #toto and #tototata.
first part of tototata is toto, isn't it ?

Comment: i've just tested with #pageView=employee&employeeCode=10 and #pageView=student, works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a link to change URL hash there is no problem using onhashchange because there is an action that change it (an anchor or a script).
Look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/FrancescoRombecchi/jxbq7epg/1/

```
<body onhashchange="myFunction()">

<p>Click the button to change the anchor part of the current URL to #part5</p>

<button onclick="changePart()">Try it</button>
<a href="#prova">Go to hello</a>
<hr>
<p id="demo"></p>

<p id="hello">hello<p>

<script>

function changePart() {
    location.hash = "part5";
    var x = location.hash;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The anchor part is now: " + x;
}

// Alert some text if there has been changes to the anchor part
function myFunction() {
    alert("The anchor part has changed!");
}


</script>

</body>
```

But, if you digit directly the url there is no action that can rise the event so it's impossible to use onshashchange function. Instead use a cookie to save the last hash and check if it is changed.

Bye